# How to call real methods of jpa repository in Junit5 mockito test cases for springboot services

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, junit5, powermockito

I have below repository interface which is getting used in my service class.

```java
@Repository
public interface InventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Inventory, Integer> {    
        Inventory findByInventoryIdAndCompanyId(Integer inventoryId, Integer companyId);   
    }
```

In My service test class, I have these two dependencies

```java
 @InjectMocks
 InventoryService inventoryService;
        
 @Mock
 InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;
```

Also, Below is my test method in the same class

```java
 @Test
 public void getInventoryByIdTest() {
        when(inventoryRepository.findByInventoryIdAndCompanyId(16591,1)).thenCallRealMethod();
        Assertions.assertEquals(16591,inventoryService.getInventoryById(16591 , 1).getInventoryId());
    }
```

I am trying to write a test case for a service and this service internally calls the JPA repository method to get the data from DB. I want to invoke the real method of the JPA repository and I want to get the real db result instead of mocking it. But it is not working and throwing the below error.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot call abstract real method on java object!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method.
```

```java
//correct example:
when(mockOfConcreteClass.nonAbstractMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

Is there any possible way to work it out?

Comment: Since you mention it is a springboot service, you will need to ensure the spring context is loaded first. The mocks you have in place doesn't load the spring context. Example - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#test-configuration-withtestconfiguration

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to replace the interface `InventoryService` with its implementation in your junit and use `@Spy` instead of `@Mock`.

**Hint**

Your test is an integration test, not an unit test. You are testing that your application comunicates without any problems with your database;
unfortunately this type of test requires many resources and too much time (let's immagine having handreds of test and each of this open a connection to the database). The unit tests are useful in order to verify the buisness logic of your application and, since they don't require a lot of resources and if they do we can use mock interfaces or services or whatever, they should take less then one second per test.

I suggest you to read [this of article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) of Martin Flower